# Apache 2 - AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, https, digital-ocean

I'm trying to set up a Godaddy SSL certificate on a DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu with Apache 2. After I've configured the certificates correctly (to the best I can see & according to the following articles:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04#step-2-configure-apache-to-use-ssl
- https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-ubuntu-server-with-apache2.htm
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04

I cannot run Apache and I'm getting the following error:

`AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl`

I've also seen this error:

`SSL Library Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routine`

both of these are in the `error.log` file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this exact error condition by simply enabling SSL under apache (by uncommenting the line in httpd.conf that loads mod_ssl and mod_socache_shmcb.so). The default httpd-ssl.conf file contains example lines of configuration with dummy values. Specifically there is a virtual host block at the bottom of this file that is provided as a template. It contains uncommented lines with dummy values. Apache won't accept these values as they are.

To test this, uncomment the above modules in httpd.conf open a console window, go to the apache\bin folder (the apache folder will have the appropriate version appended like apache2.37)

and type

```
httpd -t
```

And apache will validate your .conf files and report fatal errors. The first one you will see will report that it is unable to find server.crt. If you fill in the entire  section with the values for the website that you are trying to secure apache should stop throwing these errors.

for more detail when troubleshooting use

```
httpd -e warn
```

or

```
httpd -e debug
```

To set up a secure virtual host for a site example.com you need two  blocks.

One insecure block, and one insecure block. The insecure block uses port 80 or whatever port you choose if 80 is in use elsewhere. This is usually set up in the httpd-vhosts.conf file. The secure block is copy of the insecure block with the added commands for configuring SSL and uses port 443. This block is usually placed in httpd-ssl.conf Https-ssl.conf is automatically included in httpd.conf which is the master configuration file. It contains a conditional clause which detects the mod_ssl module and loads httpd-ssl.conf if the module is loaded. This is why the error occurs as soon as mod_ssl is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like private key is not matching certificate check on that (Not sure as i do not see full console logs). I hope the cert order is correct it should be

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is an apache.conf configuration error or any other configuration file. do this:

1. purge Apache[Uninstall/Purge Apache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671643/uninstall-apache2-from-terminal-on-ubuntu14-04/671644)
2. reload modules
3. reboot server
4. do `apachectl configtest`
5. `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`
6. `sudo systemctl status apache2.service`

That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem.
While checking, I found it was due to wrong passphrase in *pass.out* file.
It was solved after correcting that, so I suggest you to check that as well.